# Uses of selected candidate or candidate selected

Tags: difference

The selected candidates are or candidates selected are?
I was reading one article and i came across the candidates selected are ....

So Which one is correct ? Is there any differences?

Comment: "**Are** there any differences?"  Both are correct. The first one uses _selected_ as an adjective, the second is short for _the candidates who were_ or _who have been selected_.

Comment: You need to cite the full sentences. Not just a piece of one.

Comment: " The candidates selected are Kusum Shakya, Keshar Jung Baral, Govinda Subedi, Chitra Bahadur Budhathoki, Gyanendra Prasad Poudyal, Tankanath Dhamala, Tirtha Raj Khaniya, Narayan Belbase, Prakash Ghimire, Bhojraj Aryal, Mahendra Prasad Sharma, Ram Chandra Basnet, Shiva Lal Bhusal, and Surya Bahadur Thapa, as confirmed by the Ministry of Education, Science, and Technology. " This is the full sentence.

Comment: Here is a related Q/A you may find interesting: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118827/when-is-a-participle-put-before-a-noun-and-when-after

Comment: In your sentence, either option works (just like Kate Bunting said), but I believe the version where "selected" comes **after** the noun sounds more *formal* in this specific context. Since your full sentence suggests a relatively formal context, it seems like "candidates selected are..." is a marginal improvement over the alternative "selected candidates are..." (This may just be a matter of opinion)